# "handle" function is not being called in Flutter iOS plugin

Tags: swift, flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-ios

We have created a Flutter plugin where iOS code is written in Swift-

```swift
import UIKit
import CooeeSDK

public class SwiftCooeePlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
    var sdkInstance = RegisterUser.shared
    
    static public func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "cooee_plugin", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
        let instance = SwiftCooeePlugin()
        registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
    }
    
    public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        if call.method == "getUDID"{
            print(">>>getUDID 1")
            let UDID = RegisterUser.shared.fetchUDID() ?? ""
            result(UDID)
        }
    }
}
```

When we are installing this plugin in a Flutter app and calling `CooeePlugin.getUDID()` in the dart file, the above method is not being called. The weird thing is that even no error is being logged.

Any idea?

After an hour of debugging, we duplicated the same code in `channel.setMethodCallHandler` and it worked-

```swift
public class SwiftCooeePlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
    var sdkInstance = RegisterUser.shared
    
    static public func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "cooee_plugin", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
        let instance = SwiftCooeePlugin()
        registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)

        channel.setMethodCallHandler({
              (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in

              if call.method == "getUDID"{
                  print(">>>getUDID 2")
                  let UDID = RegisterUser.shared.fetchUDID() ?? ""
                  result(UDID)
              }
        })
    }
    
    public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        if call.method == "getUDID"{
            print(">>>getUDID 1")
            let UDID = RegisterUser.shared.fetchUDID() ?? ""
            result(UDID)
        }
    }
}
```

We tried to Google the issue but couldn't find any relevant reason for this.

Comment: Don't u need to `import Flutter` ?

Comment: No, without importing Flutter, it should have worked.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal were you able to find the problem? and fix?

Comment: No @iRohitBhatia. As we mentioned in the issue, we have taken that workaround only.

Comment: Would you try to test without calling 'fetchUDID' at problem code? Just call like this   'result('test')'  and check

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal can you share the dart code snippet where you are calling CooeePlugin.getUDID() ?

Comment: This is almost a year old, but I had this problem and it was just that I was not using the full name of the plugin, which was <package name>/<plugin name> where the package name is in the AndroidManifest.xml in the Android section of the plugin definition. I'm completely new to Flutter, hope this makes sense and helps somebody.